# What is the next step in the "Blow Up the Dam" mission?

Tags: battlefield-4

In battlefield 4, how do I finish the "blow up the dam" mission. I have killed all the guys and now my guys are waiting for me to do something, what is next?

Comment: please provide more information about the situation

Comment: I had the same issue, it turned out an enemy fell into the mountain (I had tagged him with the tactical binos) and my squad was trying to kill him.  Just had to keep moving forward and they forgot about him eventually.

Answer (score 1):

So you've cleared off the top of the dam and gone over the barricade? If you go along a little way the paths will split off, one will slope up on the left-hand side and the right-hand side will continue along flat. If you go along the right-hand side there is a lift that will take you to the bottom of the dam to place the charges.

See this video from around the 15:00 minute mark.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug. I had the same issue where the game wouldn't advance. It could be because I ran ahead and killed the enemies on the scaffolding from behind. I tried jumping the gap onto the ladder and fell, but when it restarted from the checkpoint my team then prompted me to jump across. It took a few goes for it to jump without falling (it wouldn't grab the ladder for some reason) but then the game did advance.